# How to get rid of some errors (expression expected, expecting newline or semicolon) in Dojo?

Tags: javascript

I try to use [the code sample](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/12/14/add-a-zoom-button-to-a-datagrid/) in my code.
When i copy `makeZoomButton` function, the IDE (jetbrains) show me some errors ( `expression expected`,`expecting newline or semicolon` and `Unclosed string literal`) in the `"zBtn = zBtn + " onClick="zoomRow('"+id+"')> </div>";"` line .
How can i get rid of the errors?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you replace the outermost double quotes to single ones?
`zBtn = zBtn + " onClick="zoomRow('"+id+"')> "` ->
`zBtn = zBtn + ' onClick="zoomRow('+id+')"> '`

Comment: Thanks @JakubJankowski. It  worked but why the example use double quotes

Comment: If you want to use double quotes (") in your string, you either need to use single quotes as opening and closing symbols for string literal, or you need to escape the single quotes using '\', this works fine: `var zBtn = "onclick=\"zoomRow()\""`